# How to implement tracking feature

Tags: java, spring, architecture

I'm thinking about the best way of implementing a way to force my service to run certain methods when an endpoint is used.

For example:
I have a Car endpoint. A user can create a car with this endpoint. When a user creates a Car the databases saves the data.

The created car can also be edited by the user. The database saves this data as well.

But the thing I want implement is a way in the background to also save the data about the old Car object and the user when a create/edit on a car is done.

I can put this logic in the service layer of my application, but since this is a vital to my application to keep track of who does the changes, this must always be in the code.

Putting the logic in my service layer might result that the code is lost/not implemented correctly.

What is good way to implement this feature?

Comment: You should use envers from hibernate. [here](https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa)

Comment: Thanks, looks good. But I forgot to mention that I'm not using Spring JPA. Is there a alternative?

Comment: May https://javers.org/documentation/spring-boot-integration/ - javers :) ?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Change Data Capture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_data_capture) pattern.

Details, on how this works for SQL Server, can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16).